# Predefined shipping ZIP Code validation during checkout in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, checkout

**What I wish to achieve**

I am trying to add a control on the checkout, making sure that the correct zip code is provided when choosing "ship to another address".

**The problem with my code**

Nothing happens with the code I am using. No message, nothing. The order can be placed no matter what.

**My question**

What is wrong or where is the error / mistake in my code?

**My code so far**

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation' , 'deny_outside_zone_message', 10, 2,);
function deny_outside_zone_message( $fields, $errors ) {

    // the accepted delivery zones
    $del_zones_array = array('30030', '30032', '30033');

    // check if the postal code (billing or shipping) if within the array
    if (! in_array('shipping_postcode', $del_zones_array ) ) {

    // if the postal is not within the array, deny checkout
    echo "The ZIP you provided is not available for oneline deliveries.";
    return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shipping_postcode` is not set in your code

```php
// Validate
function action_woocommerce_after_checkout_validation( $data, $error ) {        
    // The accepted delivery zones
    $del_zones_array = array( 30030, 30032, 30033 );

    // If the postal is not within the array, deny checkout
    if( ! in_array( $data['shipping_postcode'], $del_zones_array ) ) {
        $error->add( 'validation', 'The ZIP you provided is not available for oneline deliveries.' );
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'action_woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 10, 2 );
```